# Expand/Collapse a gridviewrow in mvvm

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, xaml, mvvm

I have a datagrid. It is bound to a collection of Patients.

Now I want to expand it when selection changes so that I could see the details of a patient.

Here is my xaml:

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Patients}" 
          SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedID}" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected"
          IsReadOnly="True" SelectionMode="Single" SelectionUnit="FullRow" >
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="VerticalCenter" TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"></Setter>
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="VerticalAndHorizontalCenter" TargetType="FrameworkElement" >
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"></Setter>
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="VerticalAndHorizontalCenterTextBlock" TargetType="TextBlock"
               BasedOn="{StaticResource VerticalAndHorizontalCenter}"/>
        <Style x:Key="VerticalAndHorizontalCenterHeader" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}" 
               BasedOn="{StaticResource VerticalAndHorizontalCenter}"/>
    </DataGrid.Resources>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding PatientName}" Header="Patient Name" Width="25*" 
                            ElementStyle="{StaticResource VerticalCenter}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding City}" Header="City" Width="15*" 
                            ElementStyle="{StaticResource VerticalAndHorizontalCenterTextBlock}" 
                            HeaderStyle="{StaticResource VerticalAndHorizontalCenterHeader}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Sex}" Header="Sex" Width="10*" 
                            ElementStyle="{StaticResource VerticalAndHorizontalCenterTextBlock}"
                            HeaderStyle="{StaticResource VerticalAndHorizontalCenterHeader}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Age}" Header="Age" Width="5*" 
                            ElementStyle="{StaticResource VerticalAndHorizontalCenterTextBlock}" 
                            HeaderStyle="{StaticResource VerticalAndHorizontalCenterHeader}"/>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Delete">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Image Source="Images/Delete.png" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>

    <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True" ItemsSource="{Binding ReportNames}">
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding ReportNames}" Header="Report Name" />
                <!--<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding DateOfReport}" Header="Date" />-->
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Delete">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Image Source="Images/Delete.png" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid>
        </DataTemplate>    
    </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>

</DataGrid>
```

Here is my ViewModel:

```
class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        using (Lab_Lite_Entities db = new Lab_Lite_Entities())
        {
            ReportNames = new List<string>();
        }
    }
    private IEnumerable<Patient> _patients;
    public IEnumerable<Patient> Patients
    {
        get
        {
            return _patients;
        }
        set
        {
            _patients = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Patients");
        }
    }

    private List<string> _reportNames;
    public List<string> ReportNames
    {
        get
        {
            return _reportNames;
        }
        set
        {
            _reportNames = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ReportNames");
        }
    }

    private int _selectedID;
    public int SelectedID
    {
        get
        {
            return _selectedID;
        }
        set
        {
            _selectedID = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedID");

            using (Lab_Lite_Entities db = new Lab_Lite_Entities())
            {
                if (SelectedID > -1)
                {

                    ReportNames.Clear();

                    if ((from p in db.Patients select p).Where(p => p.PatientID == SelectedID + 1).Select(p => p.Haemograms.Count()).FirstOrDefault() > 0)
                    {
                        ReportNames.Add("Haemogram Report");
                    }

                    if ((from p in db.Patients select p).Where(p => p.PatientID == SelectedID + 1).Select(p => p.UrineAnalysis.Count()).FirstOrDefault() > 0)
                    {
                        ReportNames.Add("Urine Analysis");
                    }

                    if ((from p in db.Patients select p).Where(p => p.PatientID == SelectedID + 1).Select(p => p.BloodChemistries.Count()).FirstOrDefault() > 0)
                    {
                        ReportNames.Add("Blood Chemistry");
                    }

                    if ((from p in db.Patients select p).Where(p => p.PatientID == SelectedID + 1).Select(p => p.WidalTests.Count()).FirstOrDefault() > 0)
                    {
                        ReportNames.Add("Widal Test");
                    }

                    if ((from p in db.Patients select p).Where(p => p.PatientID == SelectedID + 1).Select(p => p.SerologicalTests.Count()).FirstOrDefault() > 0)
                    {
                        ReportNames.Add("Serological Test");
                    }

                    if ((from p in db.Patients select p).Where(p => p.PatientID == SelectedID + 1).Select(p => p.DengueTests.Count()).FirstOrDefault() > 0)
                    {
                        ReportNames.Add("Dengue (Immunological Test)");
                    }

                    if ((from p in db.Patients select p).Where(p => p.PatientID == SelectedID + 1).Select(p => p.HIVTests.Count()).FirstOrDefault() > 0)
                    {
                        ReportNames.Add("HIV (Immunological Test)");
                    }

                    if ((from p in db.Patients select p).Where(p => p.PatientID == SelectedID + 1).Select(p => p.Troponin1Test.Count()).FirstOrDefault() > 0)
                    {
                        ReportNames.Add("Troponion-I Test");
                    }

                    if ((from p in db.Patients select p).Where(p => p.PatientID == SelectedID + 1).Select(p => p.UrinaryPregnancyCardTests.Count()).FirstOrDefault() > 0)
                    {
                        ReportNames.Add("Pregnancy Card Test");
                    }

                    if ((from p in db.Patients select p).Where(p => p.PatientID == SelectedID + 1).Select(p => p.HepatitisBSurfaceAntigenTests.Count()).FirstOrDefault() > 0)
                    {
                        ReportNames.Add("HBS Antigen Test");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my output:

[image]

As you can see from the image above I am not getting the details correctly.

I suspect that I have done some mistake in binding in the inner datagrid but I dont know how to correct it. Please suggest me some solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple of problems here:

1) Your `DataGrid` in `RowDetailsTemplate` is incorrect. You have missed `DataGrid.Columns` tag, that means you are setting both `Items` and `ItemsSource` via XAML and that causes an exception.

2) You are binding ItemsSource to a property called `ReportNames`, WPF expects that to be in your `Patient` (DataContext for each row) class - after all you are displaying Details for that Row. However, from your ViewModel code, it appears that the `ReportNames` property is not in `Patient` class but in the `MainWindowViewModel` class. Either you need to move `ReportNames` property to `Patient` class or you need to change the `Binding` to not look for `ReportNames` in `Patient` class but in `MainWindowViewModel` class. Since, I don't know your reasons for keeping `ReportNames` in `MainWindowViewModel`, I have chose to update `Binding`.

Change your RowDetailTemplate to:

```
<DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True" ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.ReportNames, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding}" Header="Report Name" />
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Delete">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Image Source="Images/Delete.png" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </DataTemplate>
</DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
```

Please note, I have assumed you have the main `DataGrid` in `Window` that's why I used `Winwow` as `AncestorType` in my `RelativeSource` binding. You may want to change that according your code.

Comment: brilliant! You have done it in minutes. I was working on this problem for last 6-7 hours. Thank you for solving my problem once again.

Comment: To find binding errors, run your app in debug mode and check output window for any WPF binding errors.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I will keep it in mind. I just wanted to ask a question. How can I use selectedItem property instead of SelectedIndex in above example as I want to have sorting enabled.

Comment: Have a property on your ViewModel like `public Patient SelectedPatient { get; set; }` and bind to `DataGrid.SelectedItem` in your View.

Comment: I tried code in above comment and it works fine. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

You just can set the Height of row detail Grid View to Auto:

```
<DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True" ItemsSource="{Binding ReportNames}" Height="Auto">
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding ReportNames}" Header="Report Name" />
            <!--<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding DateOfReport}" Header="Date" />-->
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Delete">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Image Source="Images/Delete.png" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid>
    </DataTemplate>    
</DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
```

Comment: Still I don't get any changes in the output.